# Angular not view get parameter

Tags: angular, parameters, path, get, router

I specify the route for routing.module.in ts as shown below. The link goes as if it were not.

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [


{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'activate/:code', component:ActivateComponent},
  {
    path:'reset-password' , component:ResetPasswordComponent
      },

];
```

Url: http://localhost:4200/activate/test

Activate Component:

```
export class ActivateComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { 

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let code = this.route.snapshot.params['code'];
    console.log(code)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the route params. Try this:

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.code = params['code'];            
    });
```

Comment: Apparently, all if the route was not good. The site pretends to be all if it didn't exist.
Link: http://localhost:4200/activate/test
Route: { path: 'activate/:code', component:ActivateComponent},

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  let code=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code')
```